Merge by Distance Context Menu Truncated, not showing manually enterable distance field
The context menu that pops up when Merge by Distance is chosen is truncated so I can't manually enter a desired distance. Does anyone have any suggestions of how to fix that so it shows completely? Thanks


I've noticed that if I open a file with another Blender version than the one that was used to create the file, so maybe append the objects in a brand new file?

Ok, I downloaded the latest Blender 4.1 and that fixed my problem. Thanks for your response though
